# Why my custom delegate didn't work in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here's my code.
AddItemViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class AddItemViewController, ChecklistItem;
@protocol AddItemViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)addItemViewControllerDidCancel:(AddItemViewController *)controller;
- (void)addItemViewController:(AddItemViewController *)controller didFinishAddingItem:(ChecklistItem *)item;
@end

@interface AddItemViewController : UITableViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<AddItemViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

AddItemViewController.m:

```
#import "AddItemViewController.h"
#import "ChecklistItem.h"

@interface AddItemViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
- (IBAction)Done:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)Cancel:(id)sender;

@end
...
- (IBAction)Done:(id)sender {
    ChecklistItem *item = [[ChecklistItem alloc]init];
    item.text = self.textField.text;
    item.checked = false;

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addItemViewController:didFinishAddingItem:)]) {
        [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishAddingItem:item];
    }
}

- (IBAction)Cancel:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate addItemViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}

...
```

and the ChecklistViewController call the delegate.
ChecklistViewController.m:

```
#import "ChecklistViewController.h"
#import "ChecklistItem.h"
#import "AddItemViewController.h"

@interface ChecklistViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, AddItemViewControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation ChecklistViewController
...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AddItemViewController *addItem = [[AddItemViewController alloc]init];
    addItem.delegate = self;    
}
- (void)addItemViewControllerDidCancel:(AddItemViewController *)controller{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)addItemViewController:(AddItemViewController *)controller didFinishAddingItem:(ChecklistItem *)item{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
...
@end
```

I've debug the app.When the AddItemViewController runs,the 'self.delegate' is null.Anyone can tell me what's wrong with my code please.Thank you vert much!

Comment: I edit the issue,but It still not work

Comment: I forgot to add the 'prepareForSegue' method,so the self.delegate would be nil.And  the delegate is OK now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegates are weakly held. You've set that up correctly with

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<AddItemViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

But, since it is weakly held, something else is going to have to hold a reference to that delegate object.

Also, I don't see anywhere in the code that you've posted where you are assigning the delegate object. So, a couple of things to try:

1. Make sure you assign the delegate (AddItemViewController instance.delegate = ChecklistViewController instance)
2. Make sure something else is referencing your ChecklistViewController so it doesn't go away when you need it.

Comment: I put  `AddItemViewController *addItem = [[AddItemViewController alloc]init];addItem.delegate = self; `  in the viewDidLoad method.It's still not work.

Comment: Make your addItemViewController a property or an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you assign the delegate in ChecklistViewController?  if didn't set the AddItemViewController's delegate is  ChecklistViewController instance, the delegate methods will not call.
Like this:

[image]

Hope it help.

Comment: I put the code in the 'viewDidLoad' method,but it still not work.Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Use breakpoints to help you trace through your code to see what is and isn't getting called when it should.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you already assign the delegate.

Beside that, you should check before let the delegate do anything:

```
- (IBAction)Cancel:(id)sender {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addItemViewControllerDidCancel:)]) {
         [self.delegate addItemViewControllerDidCancel:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you present the `AddItemViewController` it's not in your code.

All you have in `viewDidLoad` is :

```
AddItemViewController *addItem = [[AddItemViewController alloc]init];
addItem.delegate = self;
```

But then you don't present it , so it makes me think that it's not normal because it is local to the viewload function.

Also your are using `alloc/init` which is not  usual for `ViewController` unless you are programmatically giving it `nib` file which I doubt you are.

Most Likely You should assign the `self` delegate at the moment where you segue or present that controller.